# php replace non matches from two arrays

Tags: php, replace

How do you replace all non matches from one array that are not defined within the other array, i have kind of got working but its not exactly right. as i will show you.

the result is, but wrong.

```
- - £ 8 - - - - - - - -
```

The required result should be

```
 £ 8 - -
```

this is how my code is

```
$vals_to_keep = array(8, 'y', '£');

$replace_if_not_found = array('£', 8, '#', 't'); // replace if not in above array

$result = '';

foreach ($replace_if_not_found as $d) {
 foreach ($vals_to_keep as $ok) {
    if(strcmp($d, $ok) == 0){
    $result .= $d . " ";
    }else 
    $result .= str_replace($d, $ok ,'-') . " ";
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over all of the items in `$replace_if_not_found` replacing them with `-`, or not, as appropriate.

**Using closure in PHP 5.3 or above**

```
$result = array_map(function($item) use ($vals_to_keep) {
    return in_array($item, $vals_to_keep, TRUE) ? $item : '-';
}, $replace_if_not_found);
echo implode(' ', $result);
```

**Using a foreach loop**

```
$result = array();
foreach ($replace_if_not_found as $item) {
    if (in_array($item, $vals_to_keep, TRUE)) {
        $result[] = $item;
    } else {
        $result[] = '-';
    }
}
echo implode(' ', $result;
```

Comment: what happened to array_pad array_intersect form your first answer, that was a very neat solution

Comment: it wouldn't work for arrays like `array('£', 8, 'a', 'b', '£')`

Answer (score 1):

use in_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
foreach ($replace_if_not_found as $d) {
if (in_array($d, $vals_to_keep)) 
    $result .= $d . " ";
else 
    $result .= str_replace($d, $ok ,'-') . " ";
}
```